# Hide Url Parameters From PagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-parameters, pagedlist

The problem is that I need to pass model data to action with PagedList but the url looks ugly http://localhost:42270/ChooseLawyer?Page=2&IdLawyer=0&FirstName=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0&CurrentStatus=0&IsActive=False.I want to hide query from url.In that case I use MVC 4.
Here is my action:

```
public ActionResult SortAuthorityLawyers(AuthoritySearchViewModel model)
        {
```

In that model I want to keep search state.

```
<div class="col-md-12 mt-3" align="right">
    @pagenation @(lawyers.PageCount < lawyers.PageNumber ? 0 : lawyers.PageNumber) от @lawyers.PageCount
</div>
<div class="text-center  col-12 mb-5" style="overflow-y:auto">
    @Html.PagedListPager(lawyers, page => Url.Action(action, new { page,Model.TopagedList}))

</div>

routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "SortAuthorityLawyers",
                      url: "Избери-нов-адвокат",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "SortAuthorityLawyers" }
                 );
```

Comment: what is the structure of the `AuthoritySearchViewModel`?

Comment: public class AuthoritySearchViewModel
    {
        public int? Page { get; set; }
        public int IdLawyer { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PersonalNumber { get; set; }
        public string Bulstat { get; set; }
       
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public object ToPgedListParameters(int page)
        {
            this.Page = page;
            return this;
        }
    }

Comment: how about writing an `ajax` to pass the `model` as body to the action method